# Solving a non-linear equation in terms of known functions

Tags: numerical-methods, special-functions, nonlinear-system

I have the following equation:

$r_{*}=r+\frac{r_{+}^{2}}{\left(r_{+}-r_{-}\right)} \ln \left|r-r_{+}\right|-\frac{r_{-}^{2}}{\left(r_{+}-r_{-}\right)} \ln \left|r-r_{-}\right|$

and I need to solve for $r$, I am trying to do so in terms of known functions in hope to make the solution less numerically expensive.

For example, if $r_{-}$ is zero, I can solve for $r$ as:

$r = r_{+}\left (W\left(\frac{e^{r_{*}/r_{+} - 1}}{r_{+}}\right) + 1\right) $, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function.

In the case where $r_{-}$ is not zero I have not been able to do something similar. Is this even possible? maybe in terms of other functions?

I would very much appreciate any input, or ideas. Thank you for your time

[[image: Plot of the function in the case of <span class=]$r_{-}=0$, $r_{-}=e$, $r_{+} = 2\pi$, $2\pi<r<10\pi$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyYKA.png)

Comment: Less numerically expensive than what ?

Comment: What are typical ranges of the parameters and of $r$ ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust The parameters $r_{+}$, and $r_{-}$ are constants with $r_{+}>r_{-}$, and $0<r<\infty$ and $-\infty<r_{*}<\infty$

Comment: This is not the kind of answer I was hoping. Isn't your problem a practical one ?

Comment: @ Yves Daoust I am not sure what you mean? The ranges that I provided are the possible ranges mathematically, but when I try to solve numerically I bound the ranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For personal conveniency, I shall change notations : $a=r_+$, $b=r_-$ and $y=r_*$. To get rid of the absolute values, I shall use $\log(|t|)=\frac 12 \log(t^2)$ and do not make any hypothesis about the signs of $a$ and $b$ but assume $a>b$.

So, the equation write
$$y=r+\frac{a^2 }{2 (a-b)}\log \left((r-a)^2\right)-\frac{b^2 }{2(a-b)}\log \left((r-b)^2\right)$$ Since $a>b$, I would generate an estimate ignoring the last term. As you observed, if $b=0$, we have a solution which is now
$$r_0=a+\frac {a^2}{a-b}\,W(\pm \sqrt t)\quad \text{with} \quad t=\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^4}\exp\Bigg[ \frac{2 (a-b) (y-a)}{a^2}\Bigg]$$

For a simple test, I used $a=2\pi$, $b=e$ and $y=50$. This gives $r_0 \sim 20.558733$.

Now, Newton iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & r_n \\
 0 & 20.558733 \\
 1 & 24.157560 \\
 2 & 24.331464 \\
 3 & 24.331763
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: if I understand you correctly, you are using the case $b=0$ as an initial guess to solve using Newton's method? what I would like to have is a solution in terms of the $W$ function or other known functions for general $b$, and I am not sure if it is possible or not?

Comment: @Joel. This is exactly the point which you did notice. It is the only case where we can have an explicit solution. Being blind, I am unable to produce decent plots. If you want to make me a favor, use my example and plot on the same graph the rhs with $b=0$ and $b=e$ as a function of $r$ (for $a=2\pi$ and $a \leq r \leq 10\pi$ for example ). It will be interesting for other users

Comment: @Joel. If you do it, make it in your post. By the way, no hope for an explicit solution.

Comment: @ Claude Leibovici thanks for the idea, I have also added a plot to my post

Comment: @Joel. Thanks for doing it !